# Hide an Imageview in Monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

I am tryin to hide an imageview in monodroid using the following code.

Imagaview image = FindViewbyId(Resource.Id.UserImage);
image.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

But the image is tsill visible in the form . I tried polacing the code snipet in RunonMainUiThread also. Still the same result.

Please help me in rectifying the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that there is now just an empty space where the imageview was, then try setting the `Visibility` to `ViewStates.Gone`.

If the imageview is still showing the picture, try creating a small sample app that hides the imageview. If it doesn't work, please file a bug.